# Bug of Tk 9.0b1?

Tags: tcl, tcltk

It seems there is a bug of Tk 9.0b1.

In `/tk9.0b1/library/demos/menu.tcl`, if you remove all `"-underline ..."` options, any **Alt+key** leads to an error.

To reproduce it:

1. remove all `"-underline ..."` of `/tk9.0b1/library/demos/menu.tcl`
2. then run command: `tk9.0b1 /tk9.0b1/library/demos/widget`
3. then choose `" Menus and cascades (sub-menus) "`
4. press any Alt+key (say, Alt+S)

=> the error:

```
bad index "": must be integer?[+-]integer? or end?[+-]integer?
bad index "": must be integer?[+-]integer? or end?[+-]integer?
    while executing
"string index [$child entrycget $i -label]  [$child entrycget $i -underline]"
    (procedure "MenuFind" line 19)
    invoked from within
"MenuFind [winfo toplevel $w] $char"
    (procedure "tk::TraverseToMenu" line 14)
    invoked from within
"tk::TraverseToMenu .menu o"
    (command bound to event)
```

The cause is just in the absence of `"-underline..."` option of menubar items.

If the option is set as `"-underline -1"` (attempting to have no underlined characters), the bug remains. However, the weird `"-underline 999"` solves the problem so that you have no underlined menu characters and no bugs of Alt+key sort.

In Tk 8.6 there are no problems with this. Probably, in Tk 9.0, menu.tcl is to blame, with its `" >=0 "` clauses.

The issue looks strange as the `"-underline"` option looks mostly out-date, though useful in some cases.

Comment: Have you tried an earlier version, to see if you can replicate it with that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for bug reports. https://core.tcl-lang.org/index.html

Comment: Though it's a place to workaround them, e.g. with -underline 999 in this case. I hope also that gurus of Tcl/Tk would pay attention at this. I'm not one of them in no way.

Comment: It's just a (reportable) bug. "Oops. Forgot to handle that case." Report it and we'll fix it.